# Why log4J not working after adding apache CXF?

Tags: log4j, cxf

I have developed small web application using JSF, and i add log4j to handle logging. Everything works perfectly until i implement add web service in my web application. After implement webservice using apache CXF I'm not getting any logs in my log file, **but can get logs in eclipse console.** I don't know why, it behave like that? My log file simply show messages like [image]

i'm using jdk1.5, log4j 1.2.15 and CXF 2.6.11. Also i was tried some solutions from apache to use log4j instead of cxf default logger. please refer http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-LoggingMessages [image]

But recommended solutions are not worked for me. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: yes i have used slf4j

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that CXF introduces another log mechanism which means adds a yet another logging mechanism, or the imported versions of slf4j/log4j are not compatible. 
I would recommend you to check the CXF pom file, and exclude all the log4j/slf4j jar files.

Comment: yes your point is correct. Now your solutions is working for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As @Arash said, remove log4j from classpath (if present). Also add the file `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` to the classpath with the following content:

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger
```

Reference: [Using SLF4J Instead of java.util.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154976/custom-jaxb-binding-for-apache-cxf-wsdl2java-giving-empty-xpath-evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by removing slf4j-jdk14.jar from CXF. Actually Problem is "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings". So i removed CXF log4j binding. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks for all.